# Azure Devops Rest API - Create Pull Request Owner Issue When Using PAT

Tags: git, rest, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create pull request with createdby option like below JSON via rest api;

```
{
  "createdBy": {"id": "b568ab19-05a8-6199-9bee-95f3b7b994c9"},
  "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/hotfixes/hotfix-test-2",
  "targetRefName": "refs/heads/master",
  "title": "Merge SourceBranch to master",
  "description": "This PR Created automatically via REST API, plese do not forget to complete this PR!! ",
        "reviewers": [
            {
                "id": "a048902e-aa3b-62ac-9407-baff1ba594fb",
                "isRequired": "true"
            }
        ]
    }
```

But API method cant handle my user id on the createdBy area.
Api is using personal access token owner for this area it seems.
Because all pull requests that i created with api has same token owner.
Note that api can get this user id on reviewer area truely.

Are there anybody know detail of this behaviour?

Here the API reference about create pull request;

POST [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests?api-version=5.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7BrepositoryId%7D/pullrequests?api-version=5.0)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Comment: I guess you are trying to create pull request on behalf of someone else

Comment: yes, I need this action. But not working when give id of other users to createdBy area of json body.

Comment: Have you already tried enabling the "Make requests on behalf of others" security setting on the group the service account is in?

Comment: I gave this permission to Project Collection Build Service Account but not worked when use System.AccessToken for api call.

Comment: Also not worked with my personal token, I already gave same permission for my user.